# How to store and manipulate cards and their attributes in a TCG game

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a simple trading card game (TCG) for a school project in VB.net. I just want to state I'm fairly new to all this so am not the best at it. The game itself is based on *Hearthstone*.

I don't really understand how to store the individual cards for the game so that they can then be used to create decks, be played in a game and have their attributes manipulated. The main attributes for a creature card would be **Attack**, **Health**, **Mana** and if applicable an **Ability** (such as **Taunt** or **Charge** if you are familiar with *Hearthstone*).

I have thought about storing cards as individual structures but thought that may be inefficient and complicated. I also considered trying to store cards as txt files but then didn't know how to actually create decks out of the cards as I intended to store a deck as a txt file too. I'm not very familiar with SQL or databases so decided not to go down that route but if that is the most efficient/easiest way then how exactly would I store the cards in such a database. I've tried looking around but most of the answers correspond to actual game engines or just different languages. I thought maybe looking up chest game tutorials might help but that hasn't given me much success either.

Comment: Your thought on using "structures" is good. You would have a Card class that contained basic information and then an array/collection of filled cards that would be your deck. You don't need SQL for now. Just look at XML and read up on XML Serialization.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to review this *carefully*: [Ask]